# wp_ajax unauthenticated and authenticated

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript, content

I have build a function to fetch a post in Wordpress served over ajax.

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        data: {
          action: 'get_post_info',
          postId: postId,
        },
        success: function(data){


      });
```

In order to make it work if the user is not logged in, I have used wp_ajax_nopriv. But when the user is logged in now, the functionality crashes.

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_post_info', 'get_post_info');
function get_post_info(){
}
```

Is there a function like wp_ajax that work for both logged_in and not logged_in users?

Comment: It is best practice to declare a [ajaxurl variable](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_localize_script/#comment-1391) for non administration side usage. On the administration side `ajaxurl` is defined, see note [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins#Ajax_on_the_Administration_Side).

Answer (score 3):

```
add_action('wp_ajax_get_post_info', 'get_post_info');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_post_info', 'get_post_info');
```

[wp_ajax_nopriv_(action)](http://add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_post_info',%20'get_post_info');)
only on front-end and only for non logged users. Use [wp_ajax_(action)](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action)) for logged in users.

Answer (score 2):

As it is said in the [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_nopriv_(action))
The `wp_ajax_nopriv` hook will not fire for authenticated users, i.e. when is_user_logged_in() returns true. To handle both unauthenticated and authenticated users, also use [wp_ajax_(action)](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action)).